# What legal actions can I take to prevent my abusive parents from stalking and harassing my family?

Tags: united-states, harassment, restraining-orders, abuse, stalking

My parents were abusive when I was a child. I took legal action at age 11 and put an end the physical abuse. I moved out at age 15 and am now 20. My parents have not stopped trying to contact me. I have had to block several different phone numbers and social media platforms. They will contact anyone they think knows me, which gets very annoying for my spouse's family, my friends, etc.

All this I can deal with, however I've just had a daughter, and they are already trying to get as much information as possible on her. I'd like what they're doing to stop before my daughter is old enough for them to attempt to contact, harass, or stalk her as well.

Are there any legal actions I can take to deter them from contacting me, my family, or my spouse's family? I am in Oregon, USA.

Answer (score 2):

Oregon has laws that could result in court orders for family abuse, stalking, sexual abuse, elder/disabled abuse, and "extreme risk". All of these laws involve credible threat of physical harm, and not e.g. unwanted attempts to convert you religiously, nagging and so on. An extreme risk order is relevant if the respondent (person you want the court to rein in) is "at risk of committing suicide or harming another person in the near future". A "stalking" order relates to repeated and unwanted contact that (reasonably) alarm or coerces you, and has to boil down to a fear for your safety. The most-likely applicable law is the Family Abuse Prevention Act, [ORS 107.700-735](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_chapter_107), but again there has to be an element of fear of physical abuse. Abuse is defined as

> (a)Attempting to cause or intentionally, knowingly or recklessly
> causing bodily injury.
>
> (b)Intentionally, knowingly or recklessly placing another in fear of
> imminent bodily injury.
>
> (c)Causing another to engage in involuntary sexual relations by force
> or threat of force.

Under §107.710,

> Any person who has been the victim of abuse within the preceding 180
> days may petition the circuit court for relief under ORS 107.700
> (Short title) to 107.735 (Duties of State Court Administrator), if the
> person is in imminent danger of further abuse from the abuser.

For the sake of discussion, I assume that you have not been subject to physical abuse within the past 180 days. The only realistic step is to consult with an attorney who will ask the relevant personal questions, and can advise you whether your situation falls under existing law.